# How to multiply 2 fields together in Zoho Deluge?

Tags: zoho

Apologies if this is a simple question but I want to multiply 2 existing fields in Zoho and map the output to another field.
So for example I have an input of X for Hours and an input of Y for Hourly Rate I want to calculate X*Y and map the value to another field.
I know there are formula to do this directly in Zoho but I want to build on these calculations to include varying VAT value etc.
Is this possible in Deluge? There seems to be little information available on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Set them to variables then multiply.

```
value1 = 5;
value2 = 10;
output = value1 * value2;
info output ;
```

output = 50

if you need to get the values from a Lead or contact first, then you need to do.

```
r_lead = zoho.crm.getRecordbyID("Leads", LeadID);
```

Setting the argument LeadID to map to the Lead ID number etc.

Then if you have the values on the Lead you can get them by:

```
value1 = r_lead.get("Hours");
value2 = r_lead.get("Hourly_Rate");
```

Depending on what API names you have set for your fields.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! How would I then map the output to a blank field?

Comment: You set up a Map Value:

updatemap = Map();
updatemap.put("Field_API_Name", output);
response = zoho.crm.updateRecordbyID("Leads", LeadID, updatemap);
info response

Comment: Thank you, Jeff Tooze. I ran the script and it multiplies 2 fields and maps to a third field. I then added to it to multiply the 3rd field by a 4th field and map to a 5th field. Again, this works, but if I change a value in the 1st or 2nd field the 3rd field updates but the 5th does not. Is this perhaps a sequencing error or a limit of functions in Deluge?

Comment: If you post the full code I'll happily debug it?

Comment: r_account = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Accounts",AccountID);
 
value1 = r_account.get("Decimal_1");

value2 = r_account.get("Decimal_2");

value3 = r_account.get("Decimal_3");

value4 = r_account.get("Decimal_4");

output = value1 * value2;

output2 = value3 * value4;

updatemap = Map();

updatemap.put("Decimal_3",output);
updatemap.put("Decimal_5",output2);

response = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Accounts",AccountID,updatemap);
info response;

Comment: I posted the full code as an answer as I couldn't figure out how to post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is the full code.

```
r_account = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Accounts",AccountID);
     
    value1 = r_account.get("Decimal_1");
   
    value2 = r_account.get("Decimal_2");

    value3 = r_account.get("Decimal_3");
   
    value4 = r_account.get("Decimal_4");
    
    output = value1 * value2;
    
    output2 = value3 * value4;
   
    updatemap = Map();
    
    updatemap.put("Decimal_3",output);
    
    response = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Accounts",AccountID,updatemap);
    info response;
    updatemap.put("Decimal_5",output2);
   
    response = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Accounts",AccountID,updatemap);
    info response;
```